Can a ridden Animal Companion leap?
Riding Animal Companions says:

If it is carrying a rider, the animal companion can use only its land Speed, and [...]

Is Leap part of your "land Speed"?
For example, the Kangaroo (new Animal Companion from Howl of the Wild) has no Mount ability, and has this special feature:

When the kangaroo Leaps horizontally, it travels up to 25 feet

I think it works, as Leap is an action, not a movement type, but is this correct?

Yes, your companion can leap with its land speed
The rules for speed say

Numerous other abilities also allow you to move, from Crawling to Leaping, and most of them are based on your Speed in some way. Whenever a rule mentions your Speed without specifying a type, it's referring to your land Speed. If it is slower than 15 feet it can jump 10 feet, or it can jump 15 feet if it is faster

Note this refers to Leaping as an example for an ability that is based on your speed. However, Leap is not a "part of" land speed. Leap is an action and Speed is an attribute. The Leap action just depends for resolution on the value of the Speed attribute. The rule for the Leap action says:

Horizontal Jump up to 10 feet horizontally if your Speed is at least 15 feet, or up to 15 feet horizontally if your Speed is at least 30 feet.

This is not specifying a type, so by default, this refers to the land Speed of the creature. The companion's jumping distance will be based on its land speed, because the rules limit it to using its land speed, and how fast that is will determine how far it can jump. But jumping does not make use of its speed directly.

I feel like this is right for the wrong reasons. I don't think Leaping is 'part of' land speed; it's not a speed at all and therefore not part of the rules quoted by OP. If this doesn't inspire you to update your answer, I'll try to post one myself when I have more time.

@Ifusaso'he-him' I'll update - I think you are right.

@András, Ah, thank you -- and also that you added the source reference in the quotation you provide, as there are several sourcebooks that can have rules, this is helpful in general. You are right mine was Bestiary 3, I think because Howl of the Wild seems to be not on AoN (yet), which is my go-to source for up-to-date rules text. I will remove the PS.
